# git housekeeping - removing merged branches

Tags: git

What is the best way to clean up old branches as I am running out of space on my vm.

The git structure uses develop as the main branch and features are created off this using git flow, periodically I switch to develop and do a pull and then rebase feature branches against develop.

I am pretty new to git and I want to clean up old branches which are merged to develop as I am running out of space but I dont want to do anything to the remote repository as I am not responsible for it.

I just need to free up some space, can anyone tell me how to do this without deleting branches from the actual remote repository?

Comment: I looked at that but it suggested pushing to origin, I dont want to delete anything from the remote repository , is that what the push is doing?

Comment: Not really a duplicate, as it will not solve the problem here most probably.

Comment: @berimbolo You do not need to push the deleted branch. If you don't want to, just don't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can easily delete merged branches, it will not help you at all. A branch is just a pointer to a commit, so consumes exactly 41 bytes. (40 bytes for the sha plus a newline character). If the branch holds references to otherwise dangling commits, deleting the branch and doing some garbage collection can free up space, but if the commits are merged into another branch, they are not dangling and will remain. So it will not help at all. If you did many rebases on the branch, the reflog of the branch might hold references to otherwise dangling commits, so you can free some space by exiring the reflog and then doing garbage collection. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog and https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc for more information.

Comment: Ok is this why when I do delete branches locally and then do a git pull again I get those branches back? The branches are not deleted from the remote as far as I know.

Comment: If you delete remote tracking branches locally and do a pull, you of course get all tracking branches back, as they are in the remote repository. If you want to change this, you need to modify the fetch refspec in the config to only pull the branches you specify. If you then do a `git fetch --prune`, the not-to be fetched or deleted branches are removed from your local repository. This way you can of course save some space if you garbage collection afterwards.

Comment: You might also (alternatively or additionally) do a repack to pack the loose object files in pack files. This can also save a great amount of space, as the pack files need much less space on disk.

Comment: Ok I do every so often get a many loose objects warning. I will try this, sorry for the delayed I had a merge conflict that took some resolving and I needed to get that pushed before I could try some of this out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# delete the branches that is merged with develop branch
$ git chekcout develop
$ git branch --merged | grep -v '*' | xargs git branch -d  

# delete the branches from local that is deleted in remote
$ git remote prune origin
```

Comment: And this wont delete anything from the actual remote repository?

Comment: No, It will cleanup your local only.

Comment: And will not really help in saving space.